# Is it possible to change the linkage of Nether portals?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have 3 portals that link together, but I want to remove at least the middle one.

Edit for clarification:

[image]

The portals I created are 1, 4 and 5, the others were spawned by the game as the "other end". I want to remove the link between 5 and 4 and create a link between 5 and (the yet non-existent) 6.

The goal is to be able to travel to 5 in the route: 1, 2, 6, 5. I don't really need 3 and 4 now.

Comment: "middle" with respect to what? spacial location? a dimension between the world and the nether?

Comment: Spawned portal A in the overworld, spawned portal B in the nether, walked quite some distance and spawned portal C in the overworld. Now C links to B instead of (a new) D in the nether. I want to remove B and have C spawn a new portal in the nether so I can use it for two-way fast travel.

Comment: I think this question needs some more information, as its currently really difficult to tell what you're asking.  Can you add some more to it?

Comment: Yes I realized. I put some more effort into it, let me know if it's still unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is how I solved it:

- I deleted both 3 and 4
- I placed the player to 5 and entered the portal in-game
- This spawned a new portal (6) in the Nether because there was no portal in range to link to.

I used MCEdit because I think this is a defect in the game, but if you are not lazy like me or want to play without cheating, you can travel in the Nether from 2 and destroy 4, go back via 2, then travel to 3 in the overworld and destroy it there, then travel to 5 and enter (the numbers here correspond to the picture I added in the post).

Answer (score 8):

Nether portal have a special algorithm to link.

When you cross a portal in the overworld, it computes the nether exit by dividing the coordinates by 8 (X and Z only). Then the game look for the closest already existing portal within 128 block radius around that position. If there is one, you have your exit. If not, a portal is created.

Reversely, when comming from a nether portal, the game multiplies the coordinates by 8 and look for the closest portal within 1024 block radius around the computed coordinates.

So for the long travel idea you would need to do as this:

- Write OW coordinates. Spawn your portal and go to the nether.
- You should create a new portal (first one). Mark the location and check it is around the coordinates of your first OW portal divided by 8.
- Destruct this portal and build it as far as you can from its original location in the direction of travel, that is to say at the edge of the 128 block radius.
- Write the N coordinates and compute the equivalent OW coordinates

In this configuration, the first portal A links to B and B to A by the means of the "closest active portal" rule.

- Add a portal in the OW in the direction of travel that is closest to the last OW coordinates you have written.

You have now the new portal C linked to B (closest active portal in the nether) B to C (closest active portal in OW) and A to B (closest active portal in the nether). You can fast travel A -> B -> C now.

If you need a longer route:

- compute the nether coordinates equivalent to the C portal.
- Build a D nether portal closer to this point than portal B in the direction of the travel and repeat the operations.

The key here is to exploit the "closest" search algorithm. Do not use original spawned portals cause they are centred in the radius range. 
Warning, do not build new nether portal after this in the influence zone of your fast travel road. You could easily messed things up.

Comment: Yes, but what can I do now that I already have my portals? If I go and destroy B and B' (see my comment on the question), will it spawn a C' in the nether if I go through C from the overworld? I know I can try it but it's a reallly long distance and don't want to travel if it won't work.

Comment: Remember one thing: first time you enter the nether, it will spanw the portal real close to the (OW_X / 8; OW_Z / 8) coordinates because there is NO active portal in the nether at this time. After this, the "closest portal" rule takes precedence. Should you destroy your N portal, it would be created again if someone goes through your OW portal, UNLESS you built one within the 128 block radius, thus forcing the "closest portal" rule to apply. In your comment, you will have trouble because you can't destroy B and go back OW (unless you die?). Should you pass through C it will create a new portal

Comment: Anyway, the best option is to do the math and built portal manually. Remember: fast travel works only one way. Personally I prefer create a portal to nether, walk in nether (build roads and so) then have another portal that links my destination and vice-versa.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want, but without messed up middle links. Since I have multiple portals, I think I can destroy them without dying (it just takes a long travel :))

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

As [this page indicates](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Nether_Portal#Linkage_between_Overworld_and_Nether), the (X,Z) coordinates of the portal in the overworld should be approximately 8 times as large as the (X,Z) coordinates of the portal in the nether that you intend to link to.

So if portals are slightly misaligned, you can either build new portals or destroy existing portals in the "correct" locations (as determined by the coordinate system) to change the linkage. However, two portals that correspond correctly will never change destinations to a newly constructed portal unless one of the portals is destroyed.

Comment: Is it possible to use NBTedit or similar to do it?

Comment: You can use NBTedit to manually create and delete portals, but the mechanics behind one portal linking to another is entirely determined by the portals' location; they don't have any sort of property that you can edit to change how they connect. For that sort of functionality, you'd need to use a mod.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create portal. You have portal linkage o1 (overworld 1) to n1 (nether 1).
2. Create all portals you need on overworld.
3. Go to nether and destroy all portals.
4. In nether, create another portal (nn1) on precisely correct coordinates.

   - If o1(x,z) = (645, -662) then nn1(x,z) sould be (82,-83)  (devide by 8)
   - If there is lava, set stone block. (use creative mode)
5. Check linkage nn1 to o1.
6. Create nn2 and more on precisely correct coordinates.
7. Check all linkage.